# Ansible callbacks: get the name of the playbook being executed

Tags: python, ansible

I am playing with Ansible callbacks and would like to use the name (for example "ansible-test") of the playbook being executed within the `v2_playbook_on_start(self, playbook)` method.

So far, here is how I code my custom callback

```
class CallbackModule(CallbackBase):

    CALLBACK_VERSION = 2.0
    CALLBACK_TYPE = 'notification'
    CALLBACK_NAME = 'XXXX'
    CALLBACK_NEEDS_WHITELIST = True

    def __init__(self, display=None):
        super(CallbackModule, self).__init__(display=display)

    def v2_playbook_on_start(self, playbook):
        # How to get the playbook name?

    def v2_playbook_on_stats(self, stats):
        # ...
```

I already tried several things, but nothing works so far: 
`playbook._load_playbook_data`, `playbook.__module__`

And I can't find anything in the [docs](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/__init__.py).

How can I get this name?

Note: In my case, I can't use `playbook._basedir`

**EDIT**

Some more details to clarify my point.

So far, my structure is like the following:

```
- ansible-deploy-apache
    - defaults
        - main.yml
    - tasks
        - main.yml
    - vars 
    - ...
```

Here, the tasks the playbook execute are defined in `tasks/main.yml`.

What `playbook._file_name` gives me is `main.yml` (not the content, but just the name) from `tasks`. What I would like to have from the callback method `ansible-deploy-apache` is instead `ansible-deploy-apache`.

Comment: If `ansible-deploy-apache` is a role, `main.yml` should be a list of tasks, it can't be a playbook. Spend some time, make MCVE, so others can reproduce the behaviour in question. Folder structure, name of files, `ansible-playbook` command line.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try `_file_name`:

```
def v2_playbook_on_start(self, playbook):
    display.warning('Current playbook: {}'.format(playbook._file_name))
```

Writing plugins require some reverse engineering :)
[Context](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/2273800f7cb3e46ffbc3f4cdbd878c873691cded/lib/ansible/executor/playbook_executor.py#L81-L90) for `v2_playbook_on_start`.

Comment: Unfortunately, `_file_name` will display the name of the `.yml` file being executed (so, for example `main.yml`). However, this `main.yml` is triggered within the ansible-role (let's say `ansible-deploy-apache`), which is the name I am trying to reach. So, my struct is like `ansible-deploy-apache/tasks/main.yml`.

Comment: I doubt that **playbook** can be triggered by a role. Please add more details to your original question with [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I can't do a MCVE, since I am not allowed to publish my custom callback, and it does not matter here. I added some more details.

Answer (score 1):

This code publishes a fact for all hosts :

```
def v2_playbook_on_start(self,playbook):
    self.env = {
        "playbook_name": playbook._file_name
    }


def v2_playbook_on_play_start(self, play):  
    variable_manager = play._variable_manager
    hosts = variable_manager._inventory.get_hosts()
    for host in hosts:
        variable_manager.set_host_variable(host,"env",self.env)
```

Then in your playbook, you can simply access the fact with :

```
{{ env.playbook_name }}
```

Of course you can rename the fact as you want.